# How do I render an HTML link within a form label using a DisplayName attribute and/or LabelFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rendering, label, razor, data-annotations

I have a comment form where I am trying to render an HTML link to the Markdown reference within an HTML label. I tried adding the link to the `DisplayName` attribute in my view model:

```
[DisplayName("Comment (you can format comments with <a href=\"http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax\">Markdown</a>)")]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

Which results in the following display:
[image: Comment Body Field]

I also tried adding the label directly within the view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Comment.Body, "Comment (you can format comments with <a href=\"http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax\">Markdown</a>)")
```

But the result is understandably the same.

I realise this is because MVC is `HTMLEncoding` the output for safety, but is there any way to turn this off per label, or do I just have to manually write out an HTML label in my view in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you will have to do this manually. All HTML helpers simply HTML encode the content.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

After a 8 year gap, I encountered this problem and you can in fact use a workaround to get this working.

Change the code in your model to this:

```
[Display(Name = "Comment (you can format comments with <a href=\"http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax\">Markdown</a>)")]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

Add this into your view:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body).ToString()))
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8irIbT) to see it.